# Getting "No virtual method in class Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager " errors in sim related functions

Tags: android, telephonymanager

For example trying to use the function `getSimCarrierId()` gives the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getSimCarrierId()I in class Landroid/telephony/TelephonyManager
```

Analogous thing happpens with functions `getSimCarrierIdName()`, `getSimSpecificCarrierId()` and `getSimSpecificCarrierIdName()`.

On the other hand functions like `getSimSerialNumber()` or `getSimOperatorName()` properly work.

What could be causing such errors to appear?